# ASP.net Events in MasterPage to Page

Tags: asp.net

I have a masterpage that has a dropdownlist.
The data in the page is reliant on the dropdownlist of the master.
However, when the dropdownlist is changed, it appears the page events fire before the dropdownlist changed event in the masterpage, so the data is not updated.

The only way I can see this is working, is making the events happen in page prerender.

Anyone have a better solution?

Comment: This page explains the steps of the asp.net page life cycle: http://forums.asp.net/t/1191194.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I was able to do to make this work was move my load events to prerender events (like I mentioned in my original post) based on the the life cycle.  If anyone has a better idea, please post.